# Catching task execution with kernel module in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, task, kernel-module

I would like to know whether I can catch a task execution in a kernel module.

I would like to this module to act similar to an interrupt handler, only that it'll 
catch task/process execution instead of interrupts.

The purpose is to have the ability to log in real-time the tasks that run on the system.

Thanks in advance,
K.

Answer (score 0):

There is a netlink-based "proc connector" mechanism that can be enabled in the kernel to support this capability. A user-mode example for using it is here: 
http://bewareofgeek.livejournal.com/2945.html

It appears to be quite possible to use it from the kernel as well. There is a partial example demonstrating the mechanism in the kernel source directory under Documentation/connector/.